# How to make activerecord use a field generated on the fly by find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find-by-sql

I'm using find_by_sql with Activerecord which I generate another field there that doesn't in the original table as a combination of different fields like:

```
select (field1 + field2) as new_field_name
```

If I try to access the newly generated field like:

```
@user.new_field_name
```

I get nothing! How do you suggest I should approach this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user = select (field1 + field2) as new_field_name

This will return array although you get only one record.itearte a loop over @user

for user in @user
   puts user.new_field_name  ###this should return a sum of field1 & field2  ###
end
                          OR
if you want 1st record then

@user[0].new_field_name

Comment: But the stored values are integers!

Comment: try this 
@user[0].new_field_name  because you get the array not a single object if it works you have to put limit or itearte loop over @user.please let me know if it works ......

Comment: Thanks...One reason it didn't work work initially with my is that I had attr_accessor new_field_name in the model. It worked after removing it